# how to configure a WordPress site for heavy traffic and possible spam attack?

Tags: wordpress, performance

I need help.
I am working on a project for the common good (without commercial interest).
For this project I need a Website and it is possible that this website has many page vies  (1.000.000 per day, or even more.)
I decided to work with Wordpress (mandatory), because I'm no programmer, but I can build a simple WP-Website. I don't want to show content project to anyone before publishing. It is a kind of a secret in order to protect the idea the project.

Functionalities of the Website:
Opeen Simple Wordpress pages
3 Videos (embedded) (duration 1 hour each)
1 Download-Button in order to download the Video on local Computer
1 Download-Button in order to download a PDF on local Computer
Multilangual (WPML)
Donation function (GiveWP)
Visitors are coming mainly from Europe, North- and Southamerica

How to ensure:

- High safety
- Good page speed
- CDN?
- How to host Videos? (YouTube, Vimeo, etc… are no option, )
- Secure Backups Spam Protection.
- Is the hosting package enough for my needs? (please see details below)

I have not the possibility to contract a professional website agency, but I could contract a freelancer.
Which Plugins?
CDN necessary? Which?
Jetpack a good solution or not?
What do I need to know in order to contract a freelancer?

I would like to have some kind of coach who really knows what is important and who can guide me through the process. How to find such a specialist?

Here the hosting details I want to contract for this project:
Intel®Xeon® E5-2630 V3; 8 Corres (HT) x 2,4 GHz (2,6 GHz Turoo Boost); 64 GB RAM; 4 TB HDD

Thank you for your help. It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For hosting I would always choose some VPS(like scaleway or hetzner) and configure it myself, since you mentioned that you are not really tech person maybe you can check how much would it cost to hire someone to do it for you and compare it with hosting prices (which are pretty high nowdays).

For CDN I would say that you need it if you want speed and availability. I have experience only with Stackpath CDN and if you ask me I would recommend them since support is free and they are working 24/7 which is pretty responsive. They won't do anything on your origin server but they will do everything that needs to be done on CDN side. Stackpath is also offering WAF(Web Application Firewall) but unless you think that you will have a lot of layer 7 attacks I would avoid it since it's granting you extra security but it will cost you performance wise since there is one extra layer where requests needs to go before it's being delivered by CDN to the end users.